# Is there a Snowflake Snowpark python equivalent for 'time_slice'

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My SQL CTE looks like this:

```
with t as (
  select
    time_slice(to_timestamp_ntz(record_timestamp),5,'second') as timestamp,
    name,
    availableseconds
  from
    schemaName.dbName.tableName 
)
select count(*) from t;
```

I wanted to convert this to the Snowpark python version and so I have done this ..

```
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
from snowflake.snowpark import functions as SF
import pandas as pd 

t_session = session.table('"schemaName"."dbName"."tableName"').select(
                        SF.col("record_timestamp"),\
                        SF.col("availableseconds")
                    )
```

Although this selects the required columns from the table, I then convert this into a pandas dataframe using the .toPandas() method and then apply the 'resample('5s').first()' method.

However, this takes a long time to complete. Is there a way to invoke the 'time_slice' query within Snowpark?

I have mentioned the code I have tried above and hope to get a Snowpark API way to perform the time_slice operation.

Comment: Why not just execute the SQL statement: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.Session.sql.html

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way to invoke the 'time_slice' query within Snowpark?*

Snowpark API offers helper functions to call "native" functions that do not have Python equivalent:

> [snowflake.snowpark.functions.builtin](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.builtin.html)
>
> [snowflake.snowpark.functions.call_builtin](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.call_function.html)
>
> **Function object to invoke a Snowflake system-defined function (built-in function). Use this to invoke any built-in functions not explicitly listed in this object.**
>
> ```
> snowflake.snowpark.functions.builtin(function_name: str) → Callable[source]
> ```

```
>>> df = session.create_dataframe([1, 2, 3, 4], schema=["a"]) 
>>> df.select(call_function("avg", col("a"))).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches, using a SQL CTE and another using call_builtin(). In the below examples I used the show() to exhibit the intermediate select results. You need to replace "select *" with "select count(*)" to just get counts:

```
    sqlQuery = """  
    with t as (
      select
        time_slice(to_timestamp_ntz(RECORD_TIMESTAMP),5,'second') as 
        MONTH_TIMESLICE,
        AVAILABLESECONDS
      from
    """ + tableName +\
    """

    )
    select * from t;
    """

    df = session.sql(sqlQuery)
    df.sort(SF.col("AVAILABLESECONDS")).show()
```

Alternatively using the call_builtin() function:

```
    df_table.select(SF.call_builtin("time_slice",
         SF.col("RECORD_TIMESTAMP"),5,'second').as_("MONTH_TIMESLICE"), 
         SF.col("AVAILABLESECONDS")
         ).sort(SF.col("AVAILABLESECONDS")
         ).show()
```

Complete Code, but uses time_slice() uses MONTH instead of SECOND:

```
    import snowflake.connector
    from snowflake.snowpark import Session
    from snowflake.snowpark import functions as SF
    from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas
    import sys
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    # Set your login parameters:
    connection_parameters = {
        "account": ACCOUNT,
        "password": PASSWORD,
        "user": USER,
        "role": ROLE,
        "warehouse": WAREHOUSE,
        "database" : DATABASE,
        "schema" : SCHEMA
    }

    session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()

    # Generate some data
    def random_dates(start, end, n=10):

        start_u = start.value//10**9
        end_u = end.value//10**9

        return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

    start = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')
    end = pd.to_datetime('2022-12-15')
    days = random_dates(start, end, 5)

    data = np.random.randint(1, high=1000, size=len(days))
    df = pd.DataFrame({'RECORD_TIMESTAMP': days, 'AVAILABLESECONDS': data})

    # localize the timestamp to UTC to match expected type
    df['RECORD_TIMESTAMP'] = df['RECORD_TIMESTAMP'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')  

    #print(df.sort_values(by="AVAILABLESECONDS"))
    tableName = "Example_Table_Name"
    tableName = tableName.upper() #### < -- Use Caution if using Mixed Case Table Names

    sf_df = session.write_pandas(df, tableName, database=DATABASE, schema=SCHEMA, 
        overwrite=True, auto_create_table=True, table_type="transient")
    sf_df.sort(SF.col("AVAILABLESECONDS")).show()

    df_table = session.table(tableName).select(
                            SF.col("RECORD_TIMESTAMP"),\
                            SF.col("AVAILABLESECONDS")
                        )
    df_table.sort(SF.col("AVAILABLESECONDS")).show()

    # Query the data using SQL CTE:

    sqlQuery = """
    with t as (
      select
        time_slice(to_timestamp_ntz(RECORD_TIMESTAMP),1,'month') as MONTH_TIMESLICE,
        AVAILABLESECONDS
      from
    """ + tableName +\
    """

    )
    select * from t;
    """

    df = session.sql(sqlQuery)
    df.sort(SF.col("AVAILABLESECONDS")).show()

    # Query the data using call_builtin:

    df_table.select(SF.call_builtin("time_slice",
        SF.col("RECORD_TIMESTAMP"),1,'month').as_("MONTH_TIMESLICE"), 
        SF.col("AVAILABLESECONDS")
        ).sort(SF.col("AVAILABLESECONDS")
        ).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```html
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, sql_expr
import os
snowflake_connection_cfg = json.loads(open(os.path.expanduser('~/credentials_cas.json')).read())
session = Session.builder.configs(snowflake_connection_cfg).create()
df = session.table("tableName")
res = df.select(\
 sql_expr("time_slice(to_timestamp(record_timestamp)::timestamp_ntz,5,'second')").alias("timestamp"),\
    col("name"),\
    col("availableSeconds")).count()
print(res)
```